# How can I Change the Login screen Resolution in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, resolution

How can I Change the Login screen Resolution in 14.04?

These are my specs:

- ubuntu 14.04 amd64
- nVidia 9500 GT, 340.17 driver version
- monitor display : 1280 x 768_60.00 VGA-0

Comment: Have you tried `System settings -> Display/Monitor -> Resolution `?